# The type or namespace name 'IDependencyResolver' could not be found

Tags: c#

Im currently new to C#, and Im following a book to learn C#. I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using EssentailToos.Models;
using Ninject;

namespace EssentailToos.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver 
    {

        private IKernel kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;
            AddBindings();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            kernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();

        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run this, I get the error: `The type or namespace name 'IDependencyResolver' could not be found`

Im new to C#, so can anyone explain why I get this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add namespace of the IDependencyResolver.
Add the following line into the usings

```
using System.Web.Mvc
```